# The network connection was lost in AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

I am calling a POST Api using AFNetworking sometime it works and sometime it gives me "The network connection was lost" error. And when i try to run that API in POSTMAN it works fine. This is my code for calling post api

```
 let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()

    manager.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()
    manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()

    manager.POST(
        url,
        parameters: params,
        progress: nil,
        success: { (session, response) -> Void in
            success(response)
        }) { (session, error) -> Void in
            failure(error)
    }
```

Comment: maybe, your internet connection of your device is slow or inconsistent?

Comment: I am using the same internet connection for post man. This is the case for both Simulator and Device

Answer (score -1):

I think this is purely related to your connection, just try switching your connection or use a friends internet.